# How to launch task shortcut from resolve info?

Tags: android

I have gotten a list of shortcuts using:

```
packageManager.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT), PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
```

and I have a list of tasks which are shown to the user. Once one is clicked I use this to try to launch the activity:

```
ResolveInfo info = adapter.getItem(position);
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(name);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent, 8);
```

and it launches the shortcut but then the shortcut instantly closes with the result RESULT_CANCELED. I have no idea why it would close unless the action is wrong (I also tried using `Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`). Thanks :D

Comment: "and it launches the shortcut" -- that code has nothing to do with launching a shortcut. "I have gotten a list of shortcuts" -- that code does not get a list of shortcuts. It gets a list of activities that can create shortcuts.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the clarification, it is evident that I don't know a whole lot about this, so does this mean I need to be a launcher to be able to launch these shortcuts if I were to create them?

Comment: It's more that only the launcher knows the launcher's shortcuts. A third-party app, like yours, has no means of getting shortcuts (or much of anything else) out of a launcher.